# 127.0.0.1/8 and CIDR notation

Tags: linux

After a deep review of network and CIDR notation I often see in linux config file:

```
127.0.0.1/8
```

to set network loopback interface.

The correct CIDR should be

```
127.0.0.0/8
```

Because 127.0.0.1 is the loopback IP. Why many default linux and bsd config file use the first?

Comment: Can you specify the context? What exactly is being defined, just a prefix or a host address as well?

Comment: bind and other linux daemon for specify loopback network use 127.0.0.1/8. If I want to set a network I need to use 127.0.0.0/8 and not 127.0.0.1/8.

Comment: You didn't really answer the question, what does the setting do?

Comment: Ok, I posted a very generally phrased answer, if you post what kind of setting this actually is about I can try to answer the specific case.

Answer (score 13):

Looking at the first example, `127.0.0.1/8`, it's quite clear that it has bits set in the part of the address that is not part of the prefix (first 8 bits, as specified by `/8`).
If the goal is to just define the prefix that identifies this network, it doesn't really make any sense to include those bits, and `127.0.0.0/8` (or even `127/8`) would be the way to go instead.

However, if the goal is to specify a host address and the network's prefix length all in one go (a somewhat more modern take on the classic host IP address + netmask), `127.0.0.1/8` makes perfect sense.

It's not clear from the question but I would like to think that you have seen this in contexts where a host address is being specified.
The other alternative would seem to be that someone has made a mistake.

Answer (score 5):

In CIDR notation `127.0.0.1/8` is a means of specifying a host address and subnet mask. `127.0.0.0/8` is a means of specifying a network address and subnet mask. They're two different things, both expressed in CIDR notation.

If I say that my network address is 192.168.1.0/24 and my host address is 192.168.1.1/24 then that means that my network address is 192.168.1.0 with a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0 and my host address is 192.168.1.1 with a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0. CIDR notation can be used to represent both, as your example implies.

Answer (score 0):

Every address in the `127.0.0.0/8` address range is an IPv4 loopback address, not just `127.0.0.1`.

In many contexts, it is completely proper to refer to an address as `127.0.0.1/8` instead of the old way of using the address and mask, e.g. `127.0.0.1 255.0.0.0`.